# Iterate list values from table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables, who are joined and the ID of each table and element underneath are similar.

```
parentID | objectName | subID            ID| className| subName |
_____________________________            ________________________
    84   |   Test     |   14             14|    BOM        |   Test
    84   |   More     |   16             14|    PDF        |   Test
    84   |   Sub      |   15             15|    Schematics |   Test2
```

I want to list the categoryname and the subID of the related elements. Several ObjectNames will have several related classes.

PHP code:

```
$objects = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from subobject");


$join = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM subrelation AS subrelation INNER JOIN subobject AS subobject ON subobject.subId = subrelation.ID;");

echo "<ul>";
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_array($objects) and $row = mysqli_fetch_array($join))
{

    echo "<li>". $obj['objectName'];

    echo "<ul>";
    //ITERATION GOES HERE
    if($obj['objectName'] == $row['subName'])
        echo "<li>". "$row[className]" . "</li>";

    //END OF ITTERATION
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}   

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

and output list:

```
-Test
   -BOM
-Sub
  -Schematics
-More
```

under each field there are supposed to be more listed values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to simplify your code a bit. My guess is that your problem is occurring because you have different amounts of rows in each result set. This makes your `while` loop exit when it finishes going through the smaller result set (probably `$objects`), even though there's still more elements in the larger set.

A solution is to sort the results of your query, use just one condition in your `while` loop, and keep track of which `objectName` you're currently on using a string `$curr_objectName`:

```
$join = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM subrelation AS subrelation INNER JOIN subobject AS subobject ON subobject.subId = subrelation.ID ORDER BY subobject.objectName;');

$curr_objectName = '';

echo '<ul>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($join)) {
    $subName = $row['subName'];

    if($subName != $curr_objectName)) {
        if($curr_objectName != '') {
            #close the previous list
            #will be skipped on the first loop iteration
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</li>'; 
        }

        #start a new list
        $curr_objectName = $subName;

        echo '<li>'. $obj['objectName'];
        echo '<ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>'. $row['className'] . '</li>';
    }
}   

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: didnt really change it.. is it something with my if or do i have to do a nested if and while?

Comment: have you tried testing this on the mysql command line first to make sure the query is grabbing the results you want? if it is then you'll know it's a problem in your php.

Comment: I have. Inner join picks up some. outer join only picks up the first value of the list. I think its my php.

Comment: shouldn't it be `... ORDER BY subobject.objectName` instead of `... sort by subobject.objectName`. I don't think mysql has a `sort by` clause.

Comment: sorta. sorry added a new query at the top. thats where obj come from